# How to redirect all URLs except one path and all its subpaths without mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, redirect, apache2.4

I have Apache 2.4 in front of Tomcat 7 (altough I think just the former matters here).
I need to redirect all the requests on a domain to the HTTPS port, but not those going to a specific folder:

```
(1) http://www.example.com/ -> https://www.example.com/
(2) http://www.example.com/products -> https://www.example.com/products
(3) http://www.example.com/... -> https://www.example.com/...
```

while

```
(4) http://www.example.com/services should pass straight 
(5) http://www.example.com/services/main should pass straight
(6) http://www.example.com/services/main/list?params should pass straight
```

How can I accomplish this without using `mod_rewrite` (as I found was told in other questions)?

I saw in the docs that redirects are handled with the [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directives.

So I can handle 1,2,3 with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

but I can't write a regular expression to handle the other three. I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/3127111) that I can use negative lookarounds, but a regex like `/(?!services).*` will only match 4 (at least according to [Regex Tester on](http://regexpal.com/)

**EDIT**

I've specified that this can be accomplished without `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use regex based redirect rule here:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    ServerName www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!services).*)$ https://www.example.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

`(?!services)` is a negative lookahead that will any URL except the ones that are starting with `/services`

Comment: That's not catching `/services/other` which gets redirected.

Comment: No it will skip anything that starts with `/services`. Test in a different browser.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. That worked. Yes, I did restart Apache, I just didn't fix the other directives.

Comment: How can i achieve this with .htaccess